# how to store and retrieve utf8 characters in mysql database through Node JS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, utf-8, aws-lambda, character-encoding

I cannot store and retrieve '?' from mysql database in node js.

1. Database Creation looks like:

```
CREATE DATABASE PRODUCT CHARACTER SET UTF8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

2. Table creation looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTIONS (
        QUESTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        USER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
        QUESTION_TEXT NVARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,

        CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        LAST_MODIFIED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY (QUESTION_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET='UTF8mb4';
```

3. On the aws server, I have a lambda function which creates database pool as follows:

```
let pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: config.rds_host,
    user: config.rds_user,
    password: config.rds_password,
    port: config.rds_port,
    database: config.rds_db,
    charset: 'utf8mb4'
});
```

4. I am inserting the code in the database table as:

```
const newQuestionEntry = `INSERT INTO QUESTIONS(USER_ID, QUESTION_TEXT) VALUES(` + userID + `,` + questionText + ',' + `)`;
```

5. So for a set of values : USER_ID = 1 and QUESTION_TEXT = "How are you?", the value stored inside the Questions table is as follows:
       USER_ID = 1,
       QUESTION_TEXT = How are you 0
6. '?' is replaced by '0'.
7. I also made the following check in the mysql command line where my database resides:

```
select default_character_set_name from information_schema.SCHEMATA S where schema_name="PRODUCT";
```

to ensure that the charset format is utf8mb4. The output was as expected -- **utf8mb4**

How to solve this issue ? What is it that am i doing wrong ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blindly interpolating the Question into the INSERT statement, use "binding".  If PHP is under the covers, then it has multiple ways of achieving that.

Also, by switching the way of building queries, you can help avoid "SQL injection".

`?` is a place holder for inserting a string after it has been escaped.  By providing

```
INSERT INTO QUESTIONS(USER_ID, QUESTION_TEXT) VALUES(?, ?)
```

and then binding `userID` and `questionText`, you get the binding and escaping, while avoiding the `?` problem you are having.

Comment: Thank you very much Rick. Binding was the clear solution to this problem.